# How to perform React state update after a form submission and API fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api, setstate

I have React class component called `SearchLocationForm.js` which is a child of `App.js`. Inside of the `SearchLocationForm.js` I have this code below

```javascript
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
           error: null,
           isLoaded: false,
           coordinates: [] 
        }
        this.appid = this.props.appid;
    }

    handleSubmit(location) {

        fetch(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${location}&appid=${this.props.appid}`
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resp => this.setState({coordinates: [resp.lat, resp.lon]}))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("there has been an issue with te GeoCode API Call", error)
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LocationInput className="searchLocationForm" handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
        )
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use the `setState()` method to update the component state with the API response, and afterwards lift that up to the `App.js` component in order to make subsequent calls.

I have lookup many answers regarding this problem and have tried implementing many solutions but nothing seems to work as of now. What do you see going on within my code that seems to be causing the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to use something like overmindjs. You can then read the state from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yiu want only the coordinate will update and other states will remains same you have to use spread operator like this way

```
handleSubmit(location) {
 
  fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${location}&appid=${this.props.appid}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(resp => this.setState({...thia.state, coordinates: [resp.lat, resp.lon]}))
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error("there has been an issue with te GeoCode API Call", error)
   })

}
```

And if you want to lift the state up to the app.js, you have to define the state on app.js and set the state from this component. Read more about lifting state up from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that word of advice on the spread operator. So would it be best to define **coordinates: []** on the **App.js** component and have something like 

`<SearchLocationForm coordinates={(lat, lon) => this.setState({...this.state, coordinates: [lat, lon]})} appid={this.state.appid} />` 

where I can then replace 

**.then(resp => this.setState({...this.state, coordinates: [resp.lat, resp.lon]}))**

 with `.then(resp => this.props.coordinates(resp.lat, resp.lon))` inside of the `SearchLocationForm.js`?

Comment: I have added the full example below. Watch this

Answer (score 0):

Give you the full example. Do it like this way.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
     error: null,
     isLoaded: false,
     coordinates: [] 
  }

  handleSubmit(location) {
 
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${location}&appid=${this.props.appid}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resp => this.setState({...thia.state, coordinates: [resp.lat, resp.lon]}))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("there has been an issue with te GeoCode API Call", error)
     })

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        <SearchLocationForm state={this.state} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class SearchLocationForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {
        return (
            <LocationInput className="searchLocationForm" handleSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}/>
        )
  }
}
```